# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста! Нужна ли здесь запятая?

В качестве новинки компания представит комбинированный регулятор FRM, на давление до 10 бар.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, запятая не нужна, но всё зависит от текста.

Если перечисляются  регуляторы определенного типа на разное давление, то это определяющий признак, запятая не нужна.

Если перечисляются разные виды регуляторов, а давление является утоняющим параметром, то запятая ставится.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: тут нет никакого перечисления, уточнение присутствует в единственном числе.
запятая ставится, если идет перечисление за данным и после данного. и запятая ставится, если таких уточнений много, а приводится одно, сразу после типа прибора. если уточнение в единственном экземпляре, то запятая не ставится.
В данном случае приводится уточнение не количественное, а качественоое, указан предел давлений. значит такой прибор в единственном исполнении/
Для справки:
у приборов типа FRM давление ставится индексом сразу после наименования.